# How to stop a form from resetting automatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone tell me how I can stop my form page from displaying the results of this jquery script for only a fraction of a second before it scrolls back up to the form and resets?

What I intend to happen is for the form to scroll down to an anchor `#results` where the results are displayed. This works however the results are only displayed for a split second and the page whips back up to the form an resets.

I'm sure I should be using  `return false;` or/and `e.preventDefault();` but I'm not sure where they should go. Many thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#message").hide();
    $("#myform").validate({
        submitHandler: function() {
            $('#gauge').empty();
            var formdata = $("#myform").serialize();
            //Post form data
            $.post('php_includes/insert.php', formdata, function(data) {
                //Process post response
            });
            //Reset Form
            $('#myform')[0].reset();
            fetchRowCount();
        }
    });
    //Fetch data from server
    function fetchRowCount() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'php_includes/server.php',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                $("#rows").html(data.rows);
                $("#min").html(data.min);
                $("#max").html(data.max);
                $("#mean").html(data.total);
                $("#last").html(data.last_entry);
                //Show gage once json is receved from server
                var gage = new JustGage({
                    id: "gauge",
                    value: data.total,
                    min: data.min,
                    max: data.max,
                    title: "Sample Data"
                });
            }
        });
        //Scroll to Results
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#results').offset().top
        }, 'slow');
        $("#gauge").fadeIn(slow);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually trying to fetch the data from the server before the form data is successfully submitted.

Try putting what should be executed after the post inside its callback:

```
//Post form data
$.post('php_includes/insert.php', formdata, function(data) {
//Process post response
    //Reset Form
    $('#myform')[0].reset();
    fetchRowCount();
});
```

The same with the scroll down. You should scroll after the data is successfully fetched from the server.

```
  //Fetch data from server
  function fetchRowCount() {
      $.ajax({
          url: 'php_includes/server.php',
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(data) {
              $("#rows").html(data.rows);
              $("#min").html(data.min);
              $("#max").html(data.max);
              $("#mean").html(data.total);
              $("#last").html(data.last_entry);

              //Show gage once json is receved from server

              var gage = new JustGage({
                  id: "gauge",
                  value: data.total,
                  min: data.min,
                  max: data.max,
                  title: "Sample Data"
              });
              //Scroll to Results
              $('html, body').animate({
                  scrollTop: $('#results').offset().top
              }, 'slow');
              $("#gauge").fadeIn(slow);
          }
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need to move the scroll into the succes promise:

```
  //Fetch data from server
  function fetchRowCount() {
      $.ajax({
          url: 'php_includes/server.php',
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(data) {
              $("#rows").html(data.rows);
              $("#min").html(data.min);
              $("#max").html(data.max);
              $("#mean").html(data.total);
              $("#last").html(data.last_entry);

              //Show gage once json is receved from server

              var gage = new JustGage({
                  id: "gauge",
                  value: data.total,
                  min: data.min,
                  max: data.max,
                  title: "Sample Data"
              });

              //Scroll to Results
              $('html, body').animate({
                  scrollTop: $('#results').offset().top
              }, 'slow');
              $("#gauge").fadeIn(slow);

          }
      });
  }
```